# IOS Deep linking: Universal Links

Tags: deep-linking

Universal deep linking is not working in my code.

I had generated AASA file and is validated using aasa validator. I had added my domain in "Associated Domains" in my project target file. Domain name like this "applinks:DomainName.com".

After implementing all those things if I search in Safari "MyAppName.com", it will not redirect it to my App.

AASA (apple-app-site-association) File:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],
    "details":
            [{"appID":"xxxxxxxx.com.xxxxxx.org",
              "paths":["*","/"]}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with an actually user interaction, not just put the URL in the Safari address line.
Create simple web page with your link as an `a ref` and click on that.
This is the best test